# When form is submitted, use the value of the submission as the url

Tags: php

I am trying to create the following condition

1) User visits page
2) User enters code
3) If the code is valid, the user enters a page corresponding to the code
4) If the code is not valid, the user fails

This is so that people can view certain PDFs for an apartment rentals company.

What I would like to do, is to create a form, with an input for the special code.

When the form is submitted, it will simply redirect to url.com/[[value of input]].php

I tried creating a PHP handler to do this, but when I try it out, I get a blank page. I have limited experience with PHP, so I might be off on a completely wrong path.

Thoughts greatly appreciated on this

Here's my form

```
  <form id="enter_code" name="enter_code" action="code_handler.php" method="post">

        <label for="code">Enter Your Apartment Code</label>
        <input id="code" name="code" size="30" type="text" />

        <input class="button" name="commit" style="font-weight:normal" type="submit" value="Sign in" />

  </form>
```

and here's my code_handler.php

```
<?php

   header( 'Location: http://www.opohills.com/guests/pdf/<?=htmlspecialchars($_POST['code'], ENT_COMPAT)?>.php' ) ;

?>
```

Comment: What does your page actually return when you do the POST? Have you looked at the request and response headers in the developer console? Also, looks like you are missing the 301 or 302 status code.

Comment: Mr. Zoltan, I'm not sure how to escape them. This is my first time using PHP, apart from Wordpress. I updated the code with a slightly better version, your thoughts on what crazyness I'm writing is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why using php within php

```
header( 'Location: http://www.opohills.com/guests/pdf/'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['code'], ENT_COMPAT).'.php' ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are inside PHP code you dont need to open the quotes again:

```
<?php

   header( 'Location: http://www.opohills.com/guests/pdf/'.htmlspecialchars($_POST['code'], ENT_COMPAT).'.php' ) ;

?>
```